# How to ignore blank lines with flask-excel when import from xlsx?

Tags: excel, flask, pyexcel

I used `flask-excel` to import data from `xlsx` file. When blank lines exist in xlsx file, `pyexcel` gives `''` for empty cell and inserts `''` in every row into database. When I have a row unique, code will raise error.

Is there a simple way to ignore blank lines?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following is my solution:

```
excel_data = request.get_records(field_name='file')
# Example for excel_data: [{“k1”: “v1”, “k2”: “v2”, “k3”: “v3"}, 
#                          {“k1”: “”, “k2”: “”, “k3”: “"}]
not_null_line_data = []
for d in excel_data:
    if all(map(lambda x: x == '', d.values())):
        continue
    not_null_line_data.append(d)
# not_null_line_data:
# [{“k1”: “v1”, “k2”: “v2”, “k3”: “v3"}]
```

Github Flask-Excel Issue: [How to ignore blank lines with flask-excel when import from xlsx?](https://github.com/pyexcel/Flask-Excel/issues/13)